# Error in emmfcn(...) : Variable 'CO2' is not in the dataset in r

Tags: r, regression

I want to perform a comparison between the slope of different regressions: CO2 changes through time (day) for 8 different nests.

```
> structure(as1)
# A tibble: 16 x 4
     day  nest      N2O    CO2
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     1  0.00549 0.206 
 2     1     2  0.129   0.0343
 3     1     3  0.157   0.113 
 4     1     4  0.0760  0.106 
 5     2     1 -0.0487  0.214 
 6     2     2 -0.0561  0.358 
 7     2     3 -0.0522  0.767 
 8     2     4 -0.0193  0.188 
 9     3     1 -0.0757  0.255 
10     3     2 -0.237   0.753 
11     3     3 -0.117   0.745 
12     3     4  0.0345  0.502 
13     4     1  0.135   0.325 
14     4     2  0.264   0.767 
15     4     3  0.0116  0.926 
16     4     4  0.0342  0.358
```

I'm following the instructions given in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33013/what-test-can-i-use-to-compare-slopes-from-two-or-more-regression-models by the answer with a rate of 16.

Instead of using the library lsmeans as it suggests I used emmeans because R encourages to switch to emmeans the rest of the way. However I've also tried it with lsmeans and I get the same problem. When I run this:

```
library(emmeans)

m.interaction <- lm(CO2 ~ day*nest, data = as1)
anova(m.interaction)

# Obtain slopes
m.interaction$coefficients
m.lst <- lstrends(m.interaction, "day", var="CO2", data = as1)
```

Everything works fine until lstrends, where I get this error:

```
##Error in emmfcn(...) : Variable 'CO2' is not in the dataset
```

Does somebody know what can be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `lstrends` calls `emmfcn` and passes data to it. There is no `CO2` in your model coefficients which is probably the reason `emmfcn` can't find it. Anyway, you're using your dependent variable in `lstrends`, which is different from your linked answer, which might be the source off your error. You may also want to ask yourself if `day` and `nest` as numerical variable does make sense, IMO you should use it as categorical i.e. `factor` variables.

Comment: thank you very much! It makes sense. I'll try it